# Keep screen from going to stand-by during working hours in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, script, display, standby

Normally in Ubuntu (11.10) you either configure the screen to go to stand-by after some amount of minutes has elapsed with no user activity. Or you can configure the screen to keep turned on always.

Is there some software or script (cron?) that I can use to have the screen go to stand-by after x minuets during non-working hours, and having the screen turned on always during working hours?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a simple script that uses **xdotool** to move mouse for one pixel every x minutes ([here is how](http://michkhoo.blogspot.com/2010/10/linux-script-for-mouse-movement.html)). Additionally you can do this only when idle, what you can find with **xprintidle** variable.